# pdo and update not working correct

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am working with pdo php mysql and i am using the following script to update

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=79.170.44.155;dbname=cl36-nedal', 'cl36-nedal', 'wC-X.zfUb'); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


 $statement = $pdo->prepare("update annonce set id_compte= :id_compte , mod=:date_annonce, type= :type , section= :section ,
 vac =:vac , bien =:bien , ville=:ville , prix =:prix,sup_glob=:sup_glob , sup_hab=:sup_hab,nbr_chambre=:nbr_chambre,bains=:bains,
 etage_app=:etage_app,annee_const:=annee_const,jardin=:jardin,garage=:garage,terrasse=:terrasse,ascenseur=:ascenseur,gardiannage=:gardiannage,
 communication=:communication,securite=:securite,balcon=:balcon,picine=:picine,chem=:chem,clima=:clima,sansvi=:sansvi,park_vis=:park_vis,
 ter_imm=:ter_imm,info=:info,photo1=:p,photo2=:p1,photo3=:p2,photo4=:p3 where id_annonce =:annonce");


$statement->bindValue(':annonce',$hid);

$statement->bindValue(':id_compte',$id);
$statement->bindValue(':date_annonce',$date);
$statement->bindValue(':type',$type);
$statement->bindValue(':section',$section);
$statement->bindValue(':vac',$vac);
$statement->bindValue(':bien',$_POST['biens']);
$statement->bindValue(':ville',$_POST['villes']);
$statement->bindValue(':prix',$prix);
$statement->bindValue(':sup_glob',$sg);
$statement->bindValue(':sup_hab',$sh);
$statement->bindValue(':nbr_chambre',$nbc);
$statement->bindValue(':bains',$nbs);
$statement->bindValue(':etage_app',$etage);
$statement->bindValue(':annee_const',$annee);
$statement->bindValue(':jardin',$jardin);
$statement->bindValue(':garage',$garage);
$statement->bindValue(':terrasse',$terrase);
$statement->bindValue(':ascenseur',$ascenseur);
$statement->bindValue(':gardiannage',$gardiennage);
$statement->bindValue(':communication',$communication);
$statement->bindValue(':securite',$ss);
$statement->bindValue(':picine',$piscine);
$statement->bindValue(':balcon',$balcon);
$statement->bindValue(':chem',$cham);
$statement->bindValue(':clima',$clim);
$statement->bindValue(':sansvi',$vav);
$statement->bindValue(':park_vis',$pv);
$statement->bindValue(':ter_imm',$ti);
$statement->bindValue(':info',$info);   
$statement->bindValue(':p',$tableau[0]);
$statement->bindValue(':p1',$tableau[1]);
$statement->bindValue(':p2',$tableau[2]);
$statement->bindValue(':p3',$tableau[3]);


$statement->execute();
```

the problem is i get this answer

> Exception -> string(100) "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

what is the problem please.

Comment: Sounds like an extremely self explanatory problem. The number of values you `bind` is not the same as the number of `:placeholders` in the query.

Comment: I counted them and all are accounted for. The only possibilities are this: Your variables don't match your inputs, and/or your binds don't match your table's column(s). Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Another thing would be these `photo1=:p,photo2=:p1,photo3=:p2,photo4=:p3` where they might need to be `photo1=:p1,photo2=:p2,photo3=:p3,photo4=:p4` as a probable logical numerical sequence. Other than what I've already said, you'll need to go over everything with a fine-toothed comb ;) Plus, some of the words you have, are mispelled. `:gardiannage` and `gardiennage` so that could be it.

Comment: ...and `':chem',$cham` questionable. It leaves room for errors; be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in your query:

```
  [...snip...] annee_const:=annee_const  [...snip...]
                          ^^---
```

You've transposed the `:` and `=`. So there is no `:annee_const` parameter, hence your error.

Comment: Good catch; that could be "part" of the problem, I agree, no argument there. However, OP's code is inconsistent; spelling mostly.

Comment: the gardiannage/negge typo is only at the variable lable. the parameters/bindings are all consistent, so at best OP would be wondering why a null got bound due to the undefined variable.

Comment: Just too many typos in OP's code which is why I didn't bother putting in an answer. `':picine',$piscine)` is another I didn't mention under OP's question, amongst others. Failing on consistency, stands at tripping over logs and gators in a Lousiana Bayou ;) (My French grammar/spelling is very good, if not next to excellent).